# Confused about Android Telecom subsystem order of events on incoming calls

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

In the following link:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged

I see the quote

> Use the addNewIncomingCall(PhoneAccountHandle, Bundle) method to
> inform the telecom subsystem about the new incoming call.

This makes no sense to me. How is my app notifying the Telecom subsystem about incoming calls? Isn't it the other way? It seems like a new call enters the device and the Telecom framework routes it to an app to handle the logic, e.g. my application. How would my app ever know about an incoming call before the Telecom system? What mechanism would notify my application of an incoming call? What service or activity would even call the `addNewIncomingCall` method?

Now, my intuition says I need to use a receiver to listen for an incoming call by detecting a change in the phone state. However, the following link says that is not the proper way.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom

That instead you should be using the `inCallService` and `connectionService`, which are services I am currently using.

> Traditionally, standalone calling apps have relied on listening to the
> phone state to try to determine when other calls are taking place.
> This is problematic as the phone state does not take into account
> other calling apps the user may have installed. Using a self-managed
> ConnectionService helps you ensure that your app will interoperate not
> only with native telephony calling on the device, but also other
> standalone calling apps implementing this API. The Self-Managed
> ConnectionService API also manages audio routing and focus for you.

I'm just not sure how they fit into the bigger picture of receiving incoming calls. All the documentation says you don't need to implement the `inCallService` if you don't want your own custom user interface. But I don't see how the `connectionService` gets a reference to the `Call` object otherwise.

Does anybody have a good flow chart or other graphical representation of how the `Telecom` subsystem functions at a high level? How the callbacks work in the framework?

Ideally I want to use the default dialer interface, dial pads, everything but be notified first of an incoming call and programmatically silently reject the call or pass it through to the default dialer.

Thanks!

Comment: What about third party VOIP app. Not sure if you've seen: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/third-party-call-apps

Comment: @MorrisonChang I don't think I've seen that link. It doesn't seem to be quite what I'm looking for but I will continue reading it. I'm always open to new sources of information. It does mention "managed" vs "self-managed" `connectionService`s, which are still unclear to me so perhaps it will help with that. Thank you for your input.